# Can functions access variables defined in its own parent function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

Mozilla's Developer Resource shows two contradicting explanation regarding the function scope.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions#Functions_inside_functions)
indicates that even though a "variable is defined in the same scope as the function calls", the code will throw an error because "it is not defined inside the function definitions".

Example)

```
function myBigFunction() {
  var myValue;

  subFunction1();
}

function subFunction1() {
  console.log(myValue);
} //this will show a reference error
```

However, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope) indicates that a "function defined inside another function can also access all variables defined in its parent function and any other variable to which the parent function has access".

Example)

```
function getScore() {
  var num1 = 2,
      num2 = 3;

  function add() {
    return name + ' scored ' + (num1 + num2);
  }

  return add();
} //this is ok
```

Comment: Both are not contradictory but actually complementary.
variable scopes goes like this
function<-parent-function<---parents<---global.
In first example the variable is in local scope so its not visible to other function.
But in second example its inside a function which becomes its parent function.
So it can access parent function's scope.

Comment: The variables are declared in the parent function for both examples though

Comment: In first example there is no parent function. parent function are those which encapsulate a function. In first example, two separate function are defined.

Comment: `subFunction1();` is just called within the parent function and ***defined outside*** of parent function. Defined function signature is **`function`** `subFunction1() {...`

Comment: So is it fair to say that where the function's definition is declared matters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the first example fails and the second 'works' has to do with scope and closure. You can think of a function's 'curly braces' as the enclosure around its scope - or sphere of influence.

The first example fails because `myBigFunction()`'s variable is not accessible to `subFunction1()`'s scope. `myBigFunction()` also doesn't wrap `subFunction1()` which would provide a closure. [Check out closures here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

However, `add()` is declared within the scope of the `getScore()` function. `getScore()` 'wraps' `add()` - providing a closure so that `add()` has access to variables within `getScore()`'s scope.

Comment: Isn't the only difference between the two examples the calling of the function "add()"?  They both show the inner function wrapped within the parent function.

Comment: The first example doesn't show any 'wrapping'. The first example simple calls another function within it's scope. The difference is in the definition. Since `subFunction1()` wasn't defined within `myBigFunction()`, it doesn't have access.

Comment: When you say "wrapping", do you mean it as declaring the definition of a function within a parent function then?

Comment: Yes. This creates a closure.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example

```
function myBigFunction() {
  var myValue;

  subFunction1();
}

function subFunction1() {
  console.log(myValue);
} //this will show a reference error
```

here  myValue is included in a function `myBigFunction()` so it has a block scope.

Block scope means any code within that block (here function defines the block) can use that variable if function contain another function(function definition) and inner function using that variable then it will be passed in a closure to inner function. 2nd scenario exactly same what I explained here.

```
function getScore() {
  var num1 = 2,
      num2 = 3;

  function add() {
    return name + ' scored ' + (num1 + num2);
  }

  return add();
} //this is ok
```

In above example num1 and num2 are declared in function `getScore()`, and it has inner function `add()` since add function using num1 and num2 it will be passed as closure to `add()` function and there won't be any error while accessing those variables.

but in first example the variable is accessed out of scope and as the variable accessed outside of that function it won't be accessible and it will throw reference error.

I hope the explanation clear your understanding. to understand it thoroughly go through JavaScript scope and closure concept.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think what you're trying to say is that the block scope only extends to the inner functions that have been defined WITHIN the parent function because technically the subFunction1() and add() are both "inner functions".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `this` keyword to get parent variable i.e.

```
var bar = function () {
  this.foo = "example";//the only catch is you have to have the this key word when defining the term.
  var subfunction = function () {
    this.foo = "This an example!";
  }
}
```

(Hope this helps!)